# Calculate the expected loss in dollars?

Tags: probability, expectation

The information provided is as follows:
Assume that the daily probability of a major earthquake in Los Angeles is $.07$ percent.  The chance of your computer center being damaged during such a quake is $5$ percent.  If the center is damaged, the average estimated damage will be $\$4.0$ million.

The question is "to calculate the expected loss in dollars."

From the looks of it I would assume no calculation is to be done and the expected loss is $\$4$ million, but that seems too simple to be the correct answer.

I also performed this calculation with the feeling that $4$ million was too simple of an answer to get to. The expected loss in dollars is $51,100$ according to the $1.2775\%$ chance of this happening within a year. I got the $1.2775\%$ figure by multiplying the $.07\%$ chance and the $5\%$ chance ($0.0007\times 0.05 = 0.000035$) then multiplying the daily chance by $365$ days in a year to determine the yearly chance ($0.000035 \times  365 = 0.012775$). Then I got the $\$51,000$ figure by setting up the ratio of $\frac{1.2775}{100} = \frac{X}{4000000}$ and calculating for $X$.

Comment: What is the question here? What do we need compute?

Comment: The question is to "calculate the expected loss in dollars"

Comment: are you asking for the whole year?

Comment: Yes, for the whole year.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I apologize for improper formatting, I'm new to this website. I stumbled upon it while researching help for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Because the probability of an earthquake happening on a given day is $0.0007$, the probability of it **not** happening on a given day is $1$ - $0.0007$ = $0.9993$.

Using this number, we will calculate the probability of an earthquake **not** happening in a given year.

Let's say a year is $365$ days. Because in this question earthquakes are independent events, the probability that an earthquake would happen in a year would be $(0.9993)^{365}$, which is about $0.77$.

Remember, this is the probability that the earthquake does not happen.

The probability that it does happen is $1$ - $0.77$ = $0.23$.

Because the P(Earthquake hits your computer center) = $0.05$ and the average loss from it hitting the center is $4$ million dollars and that these events are all independent, your final answer is

$0.23$ $*$ $0.05$ $*$ $4,000,000$ = $46,000$

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check the date. This question is pretty old.